# Using activerecord migrations for a non-rails application, what are the steps?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jruby

I have a java application, and I want to use rails migrations for this.

What are the steps to get this working?

I have done this so far:

```
1. installed jruby
2. installed the following gems: rspec, cucumber, rake
```

Do I install rails or just activerecord?

Any suggestions on folder structure to store the Rakefile?  I'm assuming rake will only work on the same path where the rakefile is?

How do I tell it my db connection information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a succinct article that I believe answers all of your questions: http://community.active.com/blogs/productdev/2011/02/28/using-activerecord-3-without-rails

It talks about using AR with Sinatra but you'll see that everything is easily adapted to your problem.

Comment: The article didn't mention JRuby ... I'm seeing if I can make a write up specifically for these + JRuby.

Comment: the needed adapter for JRuby is "jdbcpostgresql"  .. but also It looks like this method is a bit different .. as its not using migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Jordan had a good answer but It was outside the context of JRuby.

If you're looking for JRuby + sinatra w activerecord migrations this is the process you want:

http://exposinggotchas.blogspot.com/2011/02/activerecord-migrations-without-rails.html

JRuby Note:

1. A gem to adapt activerecord to whatever DB
2. A modified "adapter: XXXX" declaration in config/database.yml

Example in Postgresql:

1. In file: SuperAwers0m3SinatraApp/Gemfile >> gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
2. In file: SuperAwers0m3SinatraApp/config/database.yml >> https://gist.github.com/1912785